# WebForms: Reference dynamic control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForms application that generates dynamic select elements on the page. I don't know how many will appear because that is based on how many records are in the database. Here is part of the code that executes on Page_Load.

```
foreach (int studioId in studioIds)
            {
                DataRow studio = DAL.Database.Object_Get(Database.ObjectType.Studio, studioId).Rows[0];
                var studioName = studio["name"].ToString();
                string literal = string.Format("<div class=\"form-group\">" +
                                                "<label for=\"team_filter_{0}\" class=\"col-md-3 control-label text-nowrap\">{1}</label>" +
                                                "<select id=\"team_filter_{0}\" class=\"col-md-9\" multiple=\"true\">" +
                                                "<option value=\"studio_{0}\" data-type=\"studio\">All {1}</option>", studioId, studioName);

                // ...
                literal += "<optgroup label=\"Games\">";
                literal += "<option value=\"game_0\" data-type=\"game\">All Games</option>";

                literal += "</optgroup>";

                literal += "</select>" +
                            "</div>";

                filterselectors.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(literal));
```

If you look at the select element, I generate an id (i.e. team_filter_1, team_filter_2) and append the primary key of the database record.

On this same page, I have a button that calls the following method that processes the checked options from the select list (I use the Bootstrap multiselect plugin).

```
private bool GenerateFinancialReport()
    {            
        HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect)Page.FindControl("team_filter_???");
        QueryDropDown(select, DAL.Database.ObjectType.Game, out games, out gameNames);

        // ...            
    }
```

I have two problems, I have to reference all the select elements but I don't know their id's. Secondly, I don't think I can use the FindControl method since this is not a server control. I tried hard-coding "team_filter_1" in my call to FindControl above but the select variable is always null.

I also tried to use server controls in the code-behind like the following but I still get the same problem. I'm unable to reference the dropdown lists in the code-behind when the page is posted back:

```
foreach (int studioId in studioIds)
            {
                DataRow studio = DAL.Database.Object_Get(Database.ObjectType.Studio, studioId).Rows[0];
                var studioName = studio["name"].ToString();

                // Start
                Panel formGroup = new Panel();
                formGroup.Attributes.Add("class", "form-group");

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Attributes.Add("for", "team_filter_" + studioId);
                label.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-3 control-label text-nowrap");
                label.Text = studioName;

                HtmlSelect teamfilter = new HtmlSelect();
                teamfilter.ID = "team_filter_" + studioId;
                teamfilter.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-9");
                teamfilter.Attributes.Add("multiple", "true");

                ListItem listItem = new ListItem("All " + studioName, "studio_" + studioId);
                listItem.Attributes.Add("data-type", "studio");
                teamfilter.Items.Add(listItem);

                listItem = new ListItem("All Games", "game_0");
                listItem.Attributes.Add("data-type", "game");
                teamfilter.Items.Add(listItem);

                formGroup.Controls.Add(label);
                formGroup.Controls.Add(teamfilter);
                filterselectors.Controls.Add(formGroup);
```

Comment: " I don't think I can use the FindControl method since this is not a server control."   Why don't you use (dynamically create) server controls?

Comment: @Ray have you looked at the documentation at all and example on MSDN for `HTMLSelect` [msdn HtmlSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I was thinking of using a server control but I don't know how to put it inside the .form-group div, as I do in the code above.

Comment: @Steve, I tried creating the server controls dynamically on Page_Load but my call to FindControl still returns null. What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have trouble retrieving the data from the server, especially since you aren't using server controls. I believe the best (i.e., easiest, simplest) options would probably be to grab the IDs via javascript and then pass them to the server via an ASP.NET Web API controller or by pasting a comma-separated list of the IDs into an ASP hidden input field.

Javascript to grab option values and store them would be something like this for bootstrap multiselect plugin:

```
var selectedIDs = [];
var stringVal = '';
$('div.form-group ul.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu li.active').each(function(i){
    selectedIDs.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

stringVal = selectedIDs.join();

$('#myHiddenField').val(stringVal);
```

Comment: I decided to go with this answer as it made more sense to me. However, I was forced to put my above code in Page_Init so that the controls don't dissapear on postback. The only problem I have is that the checkboxes get cleared on postback. I seem to lose this info when the user checks something and posts.